# Solving for $i$, given $S=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{A_n}{(1+i)^{t_n}}$

Tags: calculus

I'm faced with a problem that is unfortunately beyond my current mathematical skills.

I have an equation that goes like this:

$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{A_n}{(1+i)^{t_n}}
$$

My goal is to transform it so that I arrive at formula to calculate `i`. I wish I could provide my "research", but I have none as it was limited to trying to use online software in order to transform this. Otherwise it is way beyond what I'm capable of so the furthest I got is to write it down on paper.

EDIT

Since there were a couple of absolutely valid questions I thought a bit of context would be helpful. It's a formula for annual percentage rate as defined by FCA (UK's financial regulatory body). And so:

- S is the total "payable" amount
- n is the payment sequence
- A is the payment amount ($A_n$ is the payment amount for the specific payment)
- t is the "time period" measured in years ($t_n$ is the time between the specific payment date and the beginning of the commitment, e.g. for 6th payment when on a monthly basis it's going to equal 0.5, for 18th it's going to be 1.5)

Comment: What means *to transform it so that I arrive $i$*?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net apologies. Basically I need to calculate `i` and therefore I need to transform it to get a function / equation `i = ...`.

Comment: Any information about the $t_n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I updated the question with some context.

Comment: What about the $A_n$ ?

Comment: I added one more term and it is much better ... and we could continue !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, solving for $i$ the equation $$S=\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{A_n}{(1+i)^{t_n}}$$ will require numerical methods.

However, since $i \ll 1$, we can try to obtain *approximations*.

We have, by Taylor expansion or the binomial theorem
$$\frac{1}{(1+i)^{t_n}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-t_n}{k}\,i^k$$ So, truncating after the fourth power for example and summing over $n$
$$S= a_0+a_1\,i+a_2\,i^2+a_3\,i^3+a_4\,i^4+O\left(i^5\right) $$

Using for easier notations $$\Sigma_k=\sum_{n=1}^m A_n\, t_n^k$$

$$a_0=\Sigma_0\qquad  a_1=-\Sigma_1\qquad a_2=\frac 1{2!}\left(\Sigma_1+\Sigma_2 \right)\qquad a_3=-\frac 1{3!}\left(2\Sigma_1+3\Sigma_2+\Sigma_3 \right)$$
$$a_4=\frac 1{4!}\left(\Sigma_1+11 \Sigma_2+6 \Sigma_3+\Sigma_4\right)$$
Now, using series reversion, the *approximation*
$$i_{(4)}=x-\frac{a_2 }{a_1}x^2+\frac{2 a_2^2-a_1 a_3}{a_1^2}x^3+\frac{-5 a_2^3+5 a_1 a_2 a_3-a_1^2 a_4}{a_1^3}x^4+
   O\left(x^5\right)\qquad\text{with}\qquad x=\frac{S-a_0}{a_1 }$$

For a first illustration, using
$$m=6 \qquad A_n=1234+56n \qquad t_n=p_n \qquad S=7000$$this would give $i_{(4)}=0.0301004$ while the solution is $i=0.0301207$.

Try it with some data of yours; if it is more or less acceptable, we could improve it using mor terms for a better and better accuracy.

**Edit**

As said in comments, if you want a very accurate solution, use Newton method with $i_0=\frac{S-a_0}{a_1 }$. For the worked example (and a ridiculous number of figures), the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & I_k \\
 0 & 0.025945022825051725837 \\
 1 & 0.030036719253941629330 \\
 2 & 0.030120651266811630596 \\
 3 & 0.030120685453289100601 \\
 4 & 0.030120685453294768411
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, very informative! I will mark this as an answer because it's by far the most comprehensive and provides a numeric example too. I haven't tried with any of the data I have yet, but I definitely will. I did however realised that the equation I found is almost identical to XIRR equation. I will definitely give it a try and compare the result to XIRR using bisection method.

Comment: @pzaj. Do not use bsection method but Newton or Halley or Householder. These would converge so quick. I shall add for the working example.

Answer (score 2):

If you could solve for $i$, then you could solve for $v=\frac1{1+i}$ the equation $-S+\sum_{n=1}^m A_n v^{t_n}=0$. Even in a simplistic special case where all the $t_n$-s are natural numbers, solving explicitly a general polynomial equation would be impossible by any reasonable algebraic tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical annuity problem with unknown interest rate. These are known to have no analytical solution. Newton's method is appropriate for a numerical solution.

Comment: I I found Newton's method application to this very specific problem, unfortunately it doesn't work very well. I do appreciate the answer though, it steered me in the right direction.

Comment: @pzaj: I does work very well usually.